# Is sem_timedwait with EINTR-check guaranteed to wait >= the specified time?

Tags: c, semaphore, interrupt, eintr

An oft-recommended approach to timed-waiting on a semaphore is (simplified for brevity):

```
struct timespec ts;
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts);
ts.tv_sec += 5;
ts.tv_nsec += 3;
while (sem_timedwait(&sem, &ts) == -1 && errno == EINTR)
    continue;
```

Assuming the semaphore is not posted-to (i.e. timeout is expected), is the while-loop *guaranteed* to exit at the time specified in `ts` (or slightly later)? I.e. is it guaranteed that the while-loop will not exit *before* the time specified in `ts`?

I half-remember observing `sem_timedwait()` exiting slightly *before* the time specified in `ts` - *but I can't remember if that was because I didn't use the `EINTR`-check*. I do remember that there was a time I didn't quite understand what the `EINTR`-check was for, so I used `sem_timedwait()` alone, not in combination with the while-loop and `EINTR`-check_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Assuming the semaphore is not posted-to (i.e. timeout is expected), is
>   the while-loop guaranteed to exit at the time specified in ts (or
>   slightly later)? I.e. is it guaranteed that the while-loop will not
>   exit before the time specified in ts?

It depends on what you mean by "guaranteed", but [the specifications](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sem_timedwait.html) for `sem_timedwait` do not provide for it to time out before the specified time has expired.  It can fail sooner for other reasons, though, so in that sense no, it is not guaranteed that the example `while` loop will run for the full time specified.

In particular, even if all the arguments are valid and the call is not interrupted by a signal, `sem_timedwait()` is explicitly permitted to fail with `EDEADLK` to indicate that a deadlock was detected.